# How can I DRY out this Ruby Code

Tags: ruby, refactoring, dry

How can I DRY out the following Ruby Code:

```
    x = 'a random string to be formated'
    x = x.split('^')[0] if x.include?('^')
    x = x.split('$')[0] if x.include?('$')
    x = x.split('*')[0] if x.include?('*')
```

I'm looking for the amazingly elegant ruby one liner but I'm having a hard time finding it.
It should probably be somewhat readable though.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for

`x.split(/\^|\$|\*/)`

Comment: `x.split(Regexp.union'^', '$', '*')` is the same, but it looks less scary (the `union` method takes care of the escaping).

Comment: That's what I was looking for, and I love the union method aswell steenslag, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
x = "a random string to be formatted"
['^', '$', '*'].each { |token|
  x = x.split(token)[0] if x.include?(token)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided

```
x = 'a random string to be formated'

%w(^ $ *).each do |symbol|
  x = x.split(symbol)[0] if x.include?(symbol)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this regex:

```
string.match(/^([^^$*]+)[$^*]?/).captures[0]
```

It returns all characters up the the first occasion of `$, ^, or *`, or the end of the string.